Are old games from 2023 considered in new fide rating calculations?
I don’t have a rating yet. When I calculate my rating with the new rating rules do I consider only this year's performance for tournaments played after the the new rule was implemented or do I consider last year's performance too?


Are old games from 2023 considered in new fide rating calculations?

Yes. According to the latest rating rules - FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 March 2024:

7.1.4      A rating for a player new to the list shall be published when it is based on at least 5 games against rated opponents. This need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive rating periods of not more than 26 months are pooled to obtain the initial rating. The rating must be at least 1400.

So, the old rule of counting results going back 26 months still applies.
